# What Font creates blank space exactly the size of text

Tags: fonts

A workbook under construction in Word for students needs underlined blank spaces for students to fill in notes.
For Example, Fill in the blanks:
A digit is a _____________ that is used alone or with other symbols to represent a ________________
Filled in:
A digit is a single symbol that is used alone or with other symbols to represent a specific number.
I need a font where everything is just a properly sized underline (including spaces). If that is not available I could use a font that is just blank space and is compatible with underline in Word. Is there a font like this?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)?

Comment: Couldn't you just hold down the space key and set that block of spaces to be underlined? Or use a series of underscores as you did here?

Comment: What does "properly sized underline" mean? An underline the size of an M will be different than an underline the size of an I. Using a monospaced font might work, but you'd need to change the font for all the underlines. For Word.. simply use Underscores as you did in your question. Or set up tabs with leader characters (way more work). Word simply isn't designed to control layout to any great degree.

Comment: There are roughly 1000 such instances where I need to quickly change between the actual text and the fill-in-the-blanks. Having two separate documents is not feasible. Currently I create a style that I change the font color from black to white. This creates perfectly spaced blanks, but I want underlined blank space.  And yes I would prefer "Womb" to have more space than "lift".